# DateTime releated issue in ios/monotouch

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

I am using below code for calculating timestamp for notifications in monotouch. `dateAdded` parameter is the `DateTime` coming from server as notificationDatetime which is in `UTC` format.
But the "time" i.e. TimeSpan`is getting negative sometimes because`dateAdded`value is getting greater than`DateTime.UtcNow`, which is wrong. So,how to solve this problem in monotouch.

Code:

```cs
public static string GetTimeStamp (this DateTime dateAdded) { 
    TimeSpan time = DateTime.UtcNow - dateAdded;

    if (time.TotalDays > 7) 
        return string.Format ("on {0}", dateAdded.ToLocalTime ().ToString ("MMM dd, yyyy 'at' hh:mm tt")); 
    if (time.TotalHours > 24) 
        return string.Format ("about {0} day{1} ago", time.Days, time.Days == 1 ? "" : "s"); 
    if (time.TotalMinutes > 60) 
        return string.Format ("about {0} hour{1} ago", time.Hours, time.Hours == 1 ? "" : "s"); 
    if (time.TotalSeconds > 60) 
        return string.Format ("about {0} minute{1} ago", time.Minutes, time.Minutes == 1 ? "" : "s"); 
    else if (time.TotalSeconds > 10) 
        return string.Format ("about {0} second{1} ago", time.Seconds, time.Seconds == 1 ? "" : "s"); 
    else 
        return "a moment ago";
}
```

Comment: "_dateadded value is getting greater than DateTime.UtcNow,which is wrong_"—I'd resolve that issue first.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few things to check.

1. is `DateTime.UtcNow` correct on the device ?
2. is dateAdded really in UTC ?
3. is your server date and time correct ?
4. is `dateAdded.Kind == DateTimeKind.Utc` ?

I checked the implementation of `DateTime.Subtract()` and of the `-` operator, so (4) shouldn't have any influence as it conforms to the [specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1905yhe2.aspx):

> The Subtraction(DateTime, DateTime) method does not consider the value
>   of the Kind property of the two DateTime values when performing the
>   subtraction. [...]

So I'm suspecting a mix of (2) and (3).

Comment: How to check this on device? 1)is DateTime.UtcNow correct on the device ?

Comment: `Console.WriteLine (DateTime.UtcNow);`